# how to insert many posts in Slider with Php?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, class

i have a script im working on now and i have a simple problem but i can't solve it

the loop is not working right and posts keep repeating

and i do have 2 < div class > in the slider :

small & big2

the small have to be 6 posts then 1 big
then 6 small and 1 big
then 6 small and 1 big to work right

( repeated 3 times i mean )

and i was working a lot at the slider but without any success and really it bother me :S

the slider source code can be viewed here : http://weestates.com/slider/

and can be downloaded : ( please add slider.zip after /slider/ in the link )

this is one at my website and the best merging code i could do :

http://myguest.weestates.com/

Code :

```
<!-- Slider -->
<div class="sectionTop">
    <div class="sliderTop" style="position: relative; top: 0px; left: 0px; overflow: hidden; z-index: 1; perspective: 1000px; backface-visibility: hidden; width: 1663px; height: 518px;">
        <ul style="position: relative; cursor: move; backface-visibility: hidden; width: 3237px; left: -6474px;">
            <!-- Loop 1 -->
            <li style="width: 1069px; backface-visibility: hidden; overflow: hidden; position: absolute; left: 6474px;">
                <div class="sectionItemTop">
                    <?php
                    $newsAll = $News->showAllNews(6);
                    if($newsAll):
                        foreach($newsAll AS $news):
                        ?>
                        <div class="small">
                            <a href="<?php echo(($news->series_id) ? converter_episode($news->news_id, $news->news_title):converter_movie($news->news_id, $news->news_title)); ?>" title="<?php echo($news->news_title); ?>">
                                <img src="<?php echo(SITE_SLACH); ?>upload_imgs/<?php echo($news->img_file); ?>" class="attachment-post-thumbnail size-post-thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="<?php echo($news->news_title); ?>" height="640" width="490">
                                <div class="title"><?php echo($news->news_title); ?></div>
                            </a>
                        </div>

                        <div class="big2">
                            <a href="<?php echo(($news->series_id) ? converter_episode($news->news_id, $news->news_title):converter_movie($news->news_id, $news->news_title)); ?>" title="<?php echo($news->news_title); ?>">
                                <img src="<?php echo(SITE_SLACH); ?>upload_imgs/<?php echo($news->img_file); ?>" class="attachment-post-thumbnail size-post-thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="<?php echo($news->news_title); ?>" height="640" width="490">
                                <div class="title"><?php echo($news->news_title); ?></div>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <?php
                        endforeach;
                    endif;
                    ?>
                </div>
            </li>
            <!-- End Loop 1 -->

            <!-- Loop 2 -->
            <li style="width: 1069px; backface-visibility: hidden; overflow: hidden; position: absolute; left: 7553px;">
                <div class="sectionItemTop">
                <?php
                $newsAll = $News->showAllNews(6);
                if($newsAll):
                    foreach($newsAll AS $news):
                    ?>
                    <div class="small">
                        <a href="<?php echo(($news->series_id) ? converter_episode($news->news_id, $news->news_title):converter_movie($news->news_id, $news->news_title)); ?>" title="<?php echo($news->news_title); ?>">
                            <img src="<?php echo(SITE_SLACH); ?>upload_imgs/<?php echo($news->img_file); ?>" class="attachment-post-thumbnail size-post-thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="<?php echo($news->news_title); ?>" height="640" width="490">
                            <div class="title"><?php echo($news->news_title); ?></div>
                        </a>
                    </div>

                    <div class="big2">
                        <a href="<?php echo(($news->series_id) ? converter_episode($news->news_id, $news->news_title):converter_movie($news->news_id, $news->news_title)); ?>" title="<?php echo($news->news_title); ?>">
                            <img src="<?php echo(SITE_SLACH); ?>upload_imgs/<?php echo($news->img_file); ?>" class="attachment-post-thumbnail size-post-thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="<?php echo($news->news_title); ?>" height="640" width="490">
                            <div class="title"><?php echo($news->news_title); ?></div>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <?php
                    endforeach;
                endif;
                ?>
                </div>
            </li>
            <!-- End Loop 2 -->

            <!-- Loop 3 -->
            <li style="width: 1069px; backface-visibility: hidden; overflow: hidden; position: absolute; left: 5395px;">
                <div class="sectionItemTop">
                    <?php
                    $newsAll = $News->showAllNews(6);
                    if($newsAll):
                        foreach($newsAll AS $news):
                        ?>
                        <div class="small">
                            <a href="<?php echo(($news->series_id) ? converter_episode($news->news_id, $news->news_title):converter_movie($news->news_id, $news->news_title)); ?>" title="<?php echo($news->news_title); ?>">
                                <img src="<?php echo(SITE_SLACH); ?>upload_imgs/<?php echo($news->img_file); ?>" class="attachment-post-thumbnail size-post-thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="<?php echo($news->news_title); ?>" height="640" width="490">
                                <div class="title"><?php echo($news->news_title); ?></div>
                            </a>
                        </div>

                        <div class="big2">
                            <a href="<?php echo(($news->series_id) ? converter_episode($news->news_id, $news->news_title):converter_movie($news->news_id, $news->news_title)); ?>" title="<?php echo($news->news_title); ?>">
                                <img src="<?php echo(SITE_SLACH); ?>upload_imgs/<?php echo($news->img_file); ?>" class="attachment-post-thumbnail size-post-thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="<?php echo($news->news_title); ?>" height="640" width="490">
                                <div class="title"><?php echo($news->news_title); ?></div>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <?php
                        endforeach;
                    endif;
                    ?>
                </div>
            </li>
            <!-- End loop 3 -->
        </ul>
        <i class="i2233" style="position: absolute; right: 10px; bottom: 10px; z-index: 1000; font-style: normal; background: rgb(255, 255, 255) none repeat scroll 0% 0%; opacity: 0.2;">demo version</i>
        <i class="i2233" style="position: absolute; right: auto; bottom: auto; z-index: 1000; font-style: normal; background: rgb(255, 255, 255) none repeat scroll 0% 0%; opacity: 0.2; top: 10px; left: 10px;">demo version</i>
    </div>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="watch-prev" style="cursor: pointer;"><i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i></a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="watch-next" style="cursor: pointer;"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></a>
</div>
<!-- Slider End -->
```

what should i do to make it work correctly without repeating the loops and to make it looks like the one in the slider demo ?

Help please :(

Comment: Some hints: 1- remove all `style` from your `<div class="sliderTop">` and `<ul>` and `<li>` 2- you have to fetch all the records you want to show in the slider at once like `$newsAll = $News->showAllNews(21);` then loop through them and split them 7 by 7, then in each 7 batch, start with `<li>` then add `<div class="big2">` to the first one and the rest 6 ones the `<div class="small">` and end `</li>`. give it a try, if you could not sort it out, please let me know th post you an answer here

Comment: thats great and thank you sooooooooooooo much for helping me out :)

now i did as you said but when i add 3 loops or 1 it gives me the same result :S

here are you the last code i made as a zipped text : http://weestates.com/code.zip
and the result : http://myguest.weestates.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment, you have to fetch all the record you want to show at once.

Then loop through them and separate them 7 by 7

In each batch of 7, the first record `css class` will be `big2` and others `css class` will be `small`

Also You have to open the `<li><div class="sectionItemTop">` at the begining of each batch and close them at the end of each batch `</div></li>`.

So the code will look like this:

```
<!-- Slider -->
<div class="sectionTop">
    <div class="sliderTop">
        <ul>
            <?php
            $newsAll = $News->showAllNews(21);
            if($newsAll):
                $iCnt = 1;
                foreach($newsAll AS $news):
                    if($iCnt == 1){
                        $strClass = 'big2';
                        echo '<li><div class="sectionItemTop">';
                    }
                    else
                        $strClass = 'small';
                    ?>
                    <div class="<?php echo $strClass;?>">
                        <a href="<?php echo(($news->series_id) ? converter_episode($news->news_id, $news->news_title):converter_movie($news->news_id, $news->news_title)); ?>" title="<?php echo($news->news_title); ?>">
                            <img src="<?php echo(SITE_SLACH); ?>upload_imgs/<?php echo($news->img_file); ?>" class="attachment-post-thumbnail size-post-thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="<?php echo($news->news_title); ?>" height="640" width="490">
                            <div class="title"><?php echo($news->news_title); ?></div>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <?php
                    if($iCnt == 7){
                        $iCnt = 1;
                        echo '</div></li>';
                    }
                    else
                        $iCnt++;
                endforeach;
            endif;
            ?>
        </ul>
        <i class="i2233" style="position: absolute; right: 10px; bottom: 10px; z-index: 1000; font-style: normal; background: rgb(255, 255, 255) none repeat scroll 0% 0%; opacity: 0.2;">demo version</i>
        <i class="i2233" style="position: absolute; right: auto; bottom: auto; z-index: 1000; font-style: normal; background: rgb(255, 255, 255) none repeat scroll 0% 0%; opacity: 0.2; top: 10px; left: 10px;">demo version</i>
    </div>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="watch-prev" style="cursor: pointer;"><i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i></a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="watch-next" style="cursor: pointer;"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></a>
</div>
<!-- Slider End -->
```

Comment: Thank you soooooooooooooooooooooooo much ... it worked perfectly as i wanted